# Do Klingons refer to their battleships as "she"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, klingon, klingon-language

By long tradition in the English-speaking world, ships are called ["she"](http://www.glossophilia.org/?p=1411).  This tradition (which may predate English) continues in referring to the U.S.S. Enterprise, according to the [star trek database](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/enterprise-d)

> The U.S.S. Enterprise NCC-1701-D was a Galaxy-class starship and the
>   flagship of Starfleet. The fifth starship to be named Enterprise, she
>   was commanded by Captain Jean-Luc Picard.

We know a good deal about the Klingon language, and about the Klingons.  Do Klingons refer to their battleships as "she"?

Comment: warbirds are typically romulan ships, klingon ships have mistakenly been called warbirds, but birds of prey is probably what your looking for in reguards to the klingons

Comment: I suspect Klingons call their ships "it," though I'm totally guessing.

Comment: @Himarm : I agree.  I edited the question to refer to Klingon "battleships" instead of warbirds (which should be generic enough to cover Birds of Prey, Battle Cruisers, etc.)

Comment: @Praxis Thanks for improving my question with respect to the Star Trek universe.  However: "Modern warships are generally divided into seven main categories, which are: aircraft carriers, cruisers, destroyers, frigates, corvettes, submarines and amphibious assault ships. Battleships comprise an eighth category, but are not in current service with any navy in the world. Only the deactivated American Iowa-class battleships still exist as potential combatants, and battleships in general are unlikely to re-emerge as a ship class without redefinition." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warship

Comment: @ab2 : Good point.  It was a just a quick fix to the "Warbird" issue (as these are Romulan ships).  I'll edit it to say "ships" with no qualifier, but it's your question, so feel free to tweak as you see fit. :-)

Comment: @Praxis -- let's leave it as you edited it.  If anyone has a battleship, it is the Klingons.

Comment: @ab2 as an aside: the tradition you speak of descended from Antiquity. Except for English, all languages derived from Latin usually has a paternal form and a maternal form for nouns. The maternal form is used in such contexts, like how English uses she. It has its roots in ancient mythology identifying the world we live in as "Mother Earth", and matriarchal societies being the norm in primordial times at the dawn of civilization.

Comment: Don't get too hung up on history - if you wanted to be accurate, pretty much every single small arm in modern warfare would be considered a rifle ("a gun with a rifled barrel" - includes 9mm pistols just fine), and you wouldn't have laser cannons (literally "pipe", and shooting physical projectiles to boot) or photon torpedoes ("torpedo" used to mean "naval mine", and even today means "underwater self-propelled weapon"). "Battleship" evolved from the "Ship of the line (of battle)", which has nothing to do with how they were used in the Great War - artillery with huge range and armour.

Comment: "Warship" is the word you're looking for.

Comment: @Russell Borogrove -- Thanks, I know -- see long comment above defining current classes of warships.  However, if the battleship is to be revived, the Klingons will do it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When speaking in (or having the words translated to) English, the answer is apparently "yes".  However, the Klingon language has no grammatical differences for the sex/gender of an object or individual. The third person pronoun can be translated as either «he» or «she».

«*ghaH vIlegh jIH*» can be translated as either «I see him», or «I see her».

Thus, the modern Klingon word for a space vessel «*Duj*» has no sex/gender. It is an it - not he, not she.  It.

---

This is further reflected in how plurals are formed for different noun classes / categories of things.

The categories of things (similar to "women, fire, and dangerous things" being in a category together in [Dyirbal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyirbal_language), or how ships are gendered female, or [Japanese's numerous counters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word#Common_counters_by_category)) in Klingon are:

- Living beings capable of using language

  - Parrots do not fall into this category (see HolQeD 10:4, p. 4–5)
  - Robots are not living (sorry Data) (see [when to use -wIj and when to use -wI’](http://klingonska.org/canon/search/?file=1998-05-28-email.txt))
  - Babies, while they don't speak, ***are*** capable of using language
- Body parts
- General

So, this is how the Klingon language is structured for its categories. Unlike many Terran languages, there is no difference in the grammar for sex/gender. Space vessels are "it"s. They are not beings capable of language and they are not body parts. It's an "it".

---

The use of ship in context can be seen in Star Trek: The Undiscovered Country where the poor translation was a minor plot point:

In this, the question "What ship is that" is repeated several times.  The Klingon is «*Dujvetlh 'oH nuq, rIn?*»

*Duj* is «ship» as mentioned above.
*-vetlh* is «that» in the situation that it isn't nearby
*'oH* is translated as «it» (compare with *ghaH* which is he/she)
*nuq* is quite simply «what»
*rIn* is the verb «finished»

Together, this is a bit overly wordy translated as «that not nearby ship, what? over.»

This agrees with the script:

> SLEEPY KLINGON: (in Klingonese) What ship is that? Over.

Note the use of «*'oH*»

Going back to the Klingon Dictionary, section 5.1 describes pronouns:

> ```
> {jIH} <I, me>             {maH} <we, us>
> {soH} <you>               {tlhIH} <you (plural)>[[soH=>SoH]]
> {ghaH} <he/she, him/her>  {chaH} <they, them>
> {'oH} <it>                {bIH} <they, them>
> {'e'} <that>
> {net} <that>
> ```
>
> The pronoun {chaH}  is used when it refers to a group of
>   beings capable of using language; otherwise, {bIH}  is used.

Note the relationship between *ghaH* and *chaH* being things that can use language and *'oH* and *bIH* as things.

Thus, again, the ship is referred to as it.

---

Moving to Star Trek V (that many of us would rather forget), there is an extensive body of text that is available at [klingonska](http://klingonska.org/canon/1999-12-holqed-08-4-b.txt) which is a collection of Okrandian (Marc Okrand is the creator of Klingon) canonic material. For this, [Description of the Klingon dialog of <Star Trek V: The Final Frontier>, as prepared for the actors by Marc Okrand.](http://klingonska.org/canon/1999-12-holqed-08-4-b.txt)

In this you will see:

```
    Klaa
Enterprise? That's Kirk's ship.
{'en-tep-ray'-'a'. qIrq Duj 'oH}
```

*qIrq* is Kirk, in Klingon (pronounce it out - it is a phonetic translation). And again, we se *Duj* and *'oH*.

I will point out:

```
Scene 146
    Klaa
Track her course!
{He-Daj yI-qIm}
```

Which can be seen in

*He* is «course»
*-Daj* is a possessive suffix that has no gender. While the text is indeed referring to the ship, and it was shown to the viewer as 'her', the suffix is genderless (and doesn't care about language either).

*yI-* is the imperative prefix.
*qIm* is the verb for «pay attention»

---

The canonicity of the the Klingon Dictionary has been pondered about.  The first thing to realize is that when dealing with Klingon speaking fanbase, canonicity is a very important subject - you just can't make up words. There is a section about it on Wikipedia - [Klingon language - Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_language#Canon) about what works are considered canon.  The Klingon Dictionary was actually tweaked because of some publishing delays to agree with movie canon.  This is described in [an interview with Marc Okrand](http://www.startrek.com/article/qapla-klingon-language-creator-marc-okrand-part-1)

> Okrand: The book was originally supposed to come out at the same time Star Trek III came out, but it was delayed for reasons that are actually interesting and that I should have written down, but now I mostly forget. After I had finished it, and while nothing was happening with getting it published, the film went into postproduction. During postproduction, they changed some lines that were originally in English into Klingon, so we did something like we did with the Vulcan for Star Trek II, except I had to make it sound like the Klingon in the rest of the film, both in terms of sounds and grammar. I didn’t have the relative freedom I’d had with Vulcan. They also changed a couple of subtitles, so a Klingon line that had originally meant one thing suddenly meant something else. This, of course, meant that, in some cases, the dictionary no longer matched the film or lacked some words that were in the film. Because of the delay in publication, however, I was able to make changes to the dictionary so that all of the changes made in postproduction were incorporated into the book.

The published works match the movie canon.  Furthermore, the movie canon adhered to the book canon.

> But by the time of Star Trek V, the book had been published, so I could no longer fudge. This made the creation of dialogue for Star Trek V actually harder than it was for Star Trek III. It’s harder to follow rules than to make them up. ...

And was adjusted to match the movie:

> ... Actually, one of the actors did misspeak a line in Star Trek V in a scene that was too complex to reshoot. After Star Trek VI came out, the dictionary was reissued with an addendum to incorporate material created after Star Trek III. I figured out a way for the muffed line to make sense and match the subtitle and included that in the revised book. So the line in Star Trek V is correct after all.

Comment: Do the writers ever play around with this, i.e. have Klingons use the wrong pronoun in English? Or are we to presume that the Universal Translator is taking care of things, anyway? (My mother has lived in the US for almost 50 years, but she still occasionally uses the wrong pronoun, because Hungarian doesn't have gendered pronouns - it's either *ő* for "he/she" or *a/az* for "it".)

Comment: @Martha I suspect not. There's a level of culture they want to have, and they also want to have a complete language that is consistent with itself ([*taH pagh taHbe'*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Klingon_Hamlet) was a problem because Klingon originally didn't have the verb 'to be').  Getting into the language parts of "oh, I called your ship an it because it is an it" probably doesn't work well with the viewership and takes time away from other things. They're just happy that *Duj* is always the ship.

Comment: For more on that bit of consistency within a language, [Meet The Man Who Invents Languages For A Living](http://www.npr.org/2015/09/26/443170619/meet-the-man-who-invents-languages-for-a-living) from NPR who designed the language for Dothraki. The thing that annoyed him decades ago was with Return of the Jedi where *Yaté, yaté, yotó.* means something about selling a wookiee and *Yotó. Yotó.* means 50k no less.  Thats strange and rather inconstant for a language.

Comment: (and I hunted up the original Klingon Dictionary: "6.3 "To be" - There is no verb corresponding to English <to be> in Klingon. On the other hand, all pronouns (section 5.1) can be used as verbs, in the sense of <I am, you are,> etc." - that section was changed with a republishing of the material added in Star Trek IV)

Comment: All of this is great, except that it conflicts with what we see in the show, where they clearly do use a gendered pronoun to describe a vessel.

Comment: @MichaelT: Inspired by your comment, I just asked [a question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117372/what-language-does-leia-speak-when-disguised-as-bounty-hunter-boushh) about the language from *Return of the Jedi*.

Comment: @Richard and in those cases, they are speaking in or being understood by and individual using the language of the listener. Klingons, when speaking Klingon, do not refer to their vessels as male or female, but rather an 'everything else'.  The Klingon grammatical rules and lexicon is very clear on this matter. It might be interesting to head over to Russian.SE and ask what the transcript for the episode in Russian would be.

Comment: I think that this eloquently highlights my earlier comment that languages invented for TV shows are only useful **where they agree with the show**. Beyond that point, they're worse than useless.

Comment: @Richard that may be the case for issues of on the screen representation. However, there is a fairly significant corpus of material in Klingon that completely describes the language and its grammar along with fairly substantial written texts. As the question says "We know a good deal about the Klingon language, and about the Klingons." The answer can be given from canonical sources (again, there is a significant corpus of material to work from). All of the material about the Klingon language, as asked in the question, says that *Duj* has no gender - it is a thing incapable of language.

Comment: The agreed Canon in the trek universe is that "seen on screen" is the highest canon level. Everything else, even the manuals and encyclopedia sit below that

Comment: @Richard Then the material from Stark Trek The Undiscovered country where the Enterprise, on its way to Rura Penthe and messing up the translation into Klingon (speaking a rather archaic/formal form because they don't use the universal translator) is the one to look to (and the script writers used the material that I mentioned above - it is written by the language creator). Again, *Duj* has no gender.

Comment: @Richard I think Michael is right here. The "she" we hear is just an artifact of the translation to English for our benefit, an effect of the [Translation Convention](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TranslationConvention). Michael is basing his claim on what we know about *actual Klingon* from canon, and not on the translations of Klingon. It's completely reasonable to conclude that the translation becomes "she" because the bond, respect, or whatever the speaker has with/for the ship would make it appropriate in English.

Answer (score 14):

## Yes

In the *DS9* episode ["Sons and Daughters"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/526.htm), Martok uses "her" when referring to his Bird-of-Prey:

> **MARTOK:** I am General Martok. Welcome to the Rotarran. May you prove worthy of this ship and bring honour to ***her*** name.

Also, in the episode ["Soldiers of the Empire"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/519.htm), we have:

> **MARTOK:** Three days ago, the battle cruiser B'Moth began a patrol along the Cardassian border. They have not been heard from since. They are now reported as missing.
>
> **WORF:** It is possible ***she*** was destroyed by the Dominion. The Jem'Hadar attacked a Federation starship near the border less than a week ago.

**NOTE:** In both of these scenes, there are only Klingons speaking to Klingons with no other species present.  The dialogue should not be treated as passing through a Starfleet-issued universal translator, but rather as the exact intended meaning and sentiment conveyed by one Klingon to another.

Also, Klingon language guides and dictionaries, while canon to some extent, are a lesser canon than what we see and hear in the episodes and films.

Comment: Not to nitpick - but Worf would likely be using the Starfleet / human idiom here since he was not fully a member of the Klingon armed-forces

Comment: @NKCampbell : True, but Worf's concern for maintaining his identity means that he takes his Klingon culture very seriously --- perhaps more seriously than many Klingons living within the Empire.  These are the kinds of small details he would pay attention to.  Also, he served in the Empire under Gowron during the Klingon Civil War.

Comment: @NKCampbell : I've found an example where Martok refers to his ship as "her".

Comment: @NKCampbell has a good point. Thinking a little further, how do we know this isn't the universal translator in action, translating the pronoun to "she" for English listeners?

Comment: I'm sorry but how can the answer be Yes when the DS9 episode is in English and the question is about the Klingon language? Have you seen the episode in Klingon?

Comment: @ypercube: I've seen it in the original Klingon.

Comment: @Praxis sorry then. The link to the English subtitles page confused me ;)

Comment: @Praxis: seen *what* in the original Klingon? The episode? I highly doubt they did a version that was dubbed in Klingon. The pronoun "she" in the Klingon translation? Again, that's impossible, since Klingon doesn't have a word for "she". I'm confuzzled.

Comment: @Martha : It's a joke, a reference to Star Trek VI (*"You have not experienced Shakespeare until you have read him in the original Klingon."*). The two upvotes on my comment are obviously from folks who got the joke.

Comment: @Praxis: ah, so *that* was the whooshing sound I heard. :)

Comment: Just for clarity. in both episodes, were general Martok and Worf speaking in English or Klingon?

Comment: @keithreynolds - I think we can reasonably assume that Martok is speaking Klingon. It's worth noting that what we hear **is not the same as what the crew hear**. They can tell it's not English and can evidently force the universal translator to not function simply by 'willing it not to work'.

Comment: It wouldnt surprise me that they would be speeking in klingon and that we hear it in english, given the location and amount of dialog. Just wanted to be sure it wasnt spoken in klingong with english captions

Comment: @jpmc26 : I've addressed the universal translator issue in my answer.  I agree with Richard on this issue --- that there are no English speakers present in the scene and so the universal translator should not be in effect.

Comment: What I meant was that the show would probably have audio equivalent to what someone *would* hear using a universal translator. See [Translation Convention](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TranslationConvention) (mandatory TV Tropes warning). So how do we know that the "she" in these scenes is not purely an artifact of the translation? [MichaelT's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117358/25379) seems to suggest that it *is* just an artifact of the translation.