# What language does Leia speak when disguised as bounty hunter Boushh?

Tags: star-wars, languages, return-of-the-jedi

In *Return of the Jedi*, Leia Organa infiltrates the palace of Jabba the Hutt, disguised as a bounty hunter [named Boushh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boushh) who has "captured" Chewbacca.  She speaks a rather unusual language, characterized by a raspy intonation (presumably produced by some sort of modulator) and words that all sound like "Yaté" and "Yotó".

C-3PO is able to translate it to Basic without difficulty.  (At this point, he doesn't know it's Leia, so presumably he's really translating and not just putting on a show.)

**Do we know anything further about this language?**

For example: Does it have a name?  Does its apparently limited vocabulary have subtle nuances inaudible to human ears?

Comment: This appears to be 3 questions, not one.

Comment: @Mithrandir: I thought they were so closely related that it would be silly to post them separately.

Comment: The first two, maybe. The last one should be a separate question, i think.

Comment: @Mithrandir: I don't care so much about that one so I just took it out.  You're welcome to post it as a new question if you like.

Comment: "*Apparently limited vocabulary*" -- An Ubese might think of Galactic Basic as incredibly verbose, *yaté yotó* could break down into something like *yat-é* `came-1ps.PAST`, *yo-tó* `bounty-DEM`, where the *é* means the speaker did it in the past and combining *yo* and *tó* means "the bounty of this thing here," and the translation on-screen just added "Wookie."

Answer (score 35):

### Leia is speaking Ubese

Boushh is an Ubese and he (*she* when it is Leia disguised as Boushh) speaks **Ubese**

This is shown in the *Return of the Jedi* novelization by James Kahn:

> *"He bowed low and then spoke in **Ubese**.*
>
> *"Greetings, Majestic One.  I am Boushh."  It was a metallic language, well-adapted to the rarefied atmosphere of the home planet from which this nomadic species arose.*
>
> *Jabba spoke in the same tongue, although his **Ubese** was stilted and slow.*

And in the *Return of the Jedi* film.

Although the language was not named on screen, it was identified as such in the subtitles of the 2006 Limited Edition version on both re-mastered and original cuts, which was released on 12th of September 2006.

> *Yatay yatoh*
>
> *"I have come for the bounty on this Wookiee." - Boushh **speaking Ubese***

The [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html) for the film also confirms this:

> ***BOUSHH** (In **Ubese** subtitled)
> I have come for the bounty on this Wookiee*

---

### Legends

To get further details of the language such as why they use an amplifier we have to go into Legends and the game ***Star Wars: Galactic Backgrounds***:

> Ubese vocal cords could not produce sound above raspy whispers, making
> them difficult to understand when their voices weren't amplified.
>
> The Ubese also developed a sign language, Ubeninal, as an alternative to
> communicate with other Ubese. Ubeninal had no written form.
>
> Most Ubese  were fluent in **Ubese** language, Ubeninal and Basic, the common  language of the galaxy, although they were only literate in their own language.
>
> Ubese rarely chose to speak Basic.

Comment: It's a reasonable point, but does the Star Wars universe have a one-to-one correspondence between species and languages?

Comment: @NateEldredge added evidence from the subtitles of the film

Comment: @NateEldredge That would make for a good question, I think :) Mostly, yes, but they are exception in both ways, especially when you include "historical" (dead) languages. Though it should be noted that it's very much possible that in the scope of SW, Earth's languages might also be considered just one (or a couple) of languages - English may be very different from, say, German, to your ears and eyes, but they're actually very close (though mostly not mutually intelligible). A galactic civilization might lump it all in "Earthly" and be done with it :)

Comment: @Luaan as supporting examples, just look at all the different dialects of Chinese, even though they sound so different to a native speaker. In a way, Europeans can be said to be speaking dialects of "modern Latin". When a single planet is homogenised long enough, so will its languages

Comment: @thegreatjedi Western Europeans maybe but Eastern European will be Germanic and Slavic based. With English being an amalgam of the two with some Celtic thrown in. Indo-European might be a better term, but then you have the Basque language which appears to be its own thing

Comment: Well you get the idea. Assuming we don't nuke ourselves back to the Stone Age, in a thousand years our descendants will identifying their first language as Earthese, Martian etc. and one of its derivative dialects ;)

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn Even the western languages are heavily germanic. French developed from Frankish (language of a germanic tribe), Spanish developed from Gothic (another germanic tribe)... If you're not used to finding the differences, they all sound very much alike. Very broadly, the west is mostly germanic+romanic, the east is more germanic+slavic. But it's still just various mixes of germanic, latin and slavic influences, with the outliers incorporating finno-ugric etc. Finnish sounds a lot "weirder" to a typical European than Spanish, for example.

Comment: Great answer, but a typo on the first line make Leia a male :)

Comment: @DrakaSAN the dangers of talking about the actual Boushh and Leia in the same sentence. Hopefully reads better now

Comment: @Luaan French and Spanish both developed from Vulgar Latin; they were _influenced_, to varying degrees, by the (eventually extinct) Germanic languages spoken in the region, but they did not develop from them. Spanish was also, to a much greater degree, influenced by the Moors and their language, and French was also influenced, to a smaller degree, by Breton. Very broadly, the north and northwest is Germanic, the south and southwest is Romance, the east and northeast is Slavic, and the far southeast is Greek. And then there are the Finno-Ugric and Basque pockets strewn around here and there.

Comment: Novelisations? Pfft. Who reads those?

Comment: Curious, why would Jabba know this language?

Comment: @ThomasW I didn't think he did hence 3PO translating

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn In the quote from the Return of the Jedi novelization it says "Jabba spoke in the same tongue, although his Ubese was stilted and slow."

Comment: @ThomasW oh yeah! Haha forgot what I'd written. Maybe he'd had dealings with boushh before?

Comment: It is curious because most of the time Jabba is depected as only speaking in Huttese. I seems a bit inconsistent to me, but it is only in the novel.

Comment: While not really part of an answer, the attempt by a linguist to deconstruct this amazingly terse language at http://makealang.blogspot.com/2009/01/deconstructing-ubese-conlang.html is an amusing read.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots that linguist has too much time on their hands. Thanks for the share though :) very amusing